# Why is it 85,680??(Linear Programming) But the given is 90,000X10^3 per day

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, linear-programming

maximum of 90,000  10^3 cubic feet per day for its complexes.

but why did the das natural turn to 85,680?? Any suggestion. Thanks

This is my solution:
80(1200)+120(560)+140(540)+140(1200)+90(490)+70(160)+60(1280)+90(840) = 614,500
So I guess 90000X10^3  = 90000000

90000000 - 614,5500 = 89,385,.5500

What Formula did they use ??

[image]

Comment: There's not enough information to answer your question, but assuming it's a problem of linear programming with a constraint on overall availablity (90,000,000 cubic feet per day - seems too high, incidentally) and others pertaining to, presumably, limited processing capacity, then some of the constraints won't be fully taken up. (If they were all taken up, it wouldn't be an LP problem.) So it sounds as if the total gas constraint is one of these.

Comment: I've update already of what I've answer

Comment: My commment above was based on nothing but your words "linear programming" and the max gas available per day, so it was a pure guess. You've now added detail but I can't follow all of the figures in "this is my solution". The value of 85680 is straightforward: for each product multiply Capacity, (Production Rate)/100 and Natural Gas Usage, then add the eight resulting answers. Another guess, about what you've not asked: the 20% curtailment means that all of the products can't be made to the full, so the limited gas will be allocated in order of decreasing contribution per unit gas usage.

Answer (score 0):

`Current natural gas usage = ( 1500*80*8 + 600*90*10 + 700*70*12 + 200*80*12 + 800*70*7 + 1500*80*18 + 1600*80*20 + 1400*60*14 ) / 100 = 85680`

`Nothing to do with linear-programming.`